# Is the Polynomial $X^{p^n}-X$ the zero polynomial in characteristic $p$?

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, positive-characteristic

Suppose that $p$ is a prime number and that $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}[X]$ is the ring of polynomials with one variable, with coefficients in the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. 
Then

$p(X):=X^{p^n}-X\in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}[X]$

is a polynomial, which appears at many places in number theory, for example in the definition of the Carlitz Exponential. (In books about function field arithmetics this polynomial is often called $[1]$, where in general
$[k]:=X^{p^{n\cdot k}}-X$)

Now the question is: Since $p(X)=0$ for any $X\in\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, isn't $f$ just the zero polynomial? The same should be true for all $[k]$, but as this is not mentioned in any book on function field arithmetic, I think I might overlook something.

Maybe someone has something enlightening to say here.

Comment: Generally speaking, two polynomials over a field are said to be "the same" if their coefficients match.  Or, equivalently, if their values are the same over an algebraic closure of the field.  So, no...these aren't the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not. The zero polynomial has degree $-\infty$ whereas this polynomial has degree $p^n$. Moreover, $x^{p^n}-x$ has a unique factorization as it is a polynomial over a field, whereas $0$ is infinitely divisible by anything. The key disconnect here is that you are only considering solutions in $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ and you are thinking that a polynomial is determined by its values on too small a set--remember that polynomials of degree $n$ are determined by their values on sets of size $n+1$, so you have a bunch of zeros, but you are missing a final point to uniquely identify this polynomial, and if you take any field extension of $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ you get a non-zero output for that input, which is different from the zero polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

$X^{p^n}-X$ is clearly not the zero polynomial because it has nonzero coefficients.

However, $X^{p^n}-X$ does induce the zero *function*.

In fact, the polynomials that induce the zero function are exactly the multiples of $X^{p^n}-X$.

In general, if $K$ is a field, then there is a homomorphism of $K$-algebras $K[X] \to K^K$ that transforms polynomials into functions. This map is injective iff $K$ is infinite. When $K$ is finite with $q$ elements, the kernel is generated by $X^q-X$. This is a consequence of Lagrange's theorem in group theory applied to $K^\times$.

Comment: Good answer. However I can only choose one.

Answer (score 0):

In abstract algebra, by *(univariate) (abstract) polynomial* (over a ring $R$) one means a formal linear combination
$$p(X) := a_n X^n + a_{n - 1} X^{n - 1} + \cdots + a_1 X + a_0$$
of $1, X, \ldots, X^{n - 1}, X^n$, where $X$ is an indeterminate and $a_0, \ldots, a_n \in R$.

Any (univariate) polynomial over $R$ determines a *polynomial function* $p : R \to R$ defined by
$$x \mapsto p(x) .$$
In the most familiar setting, where $R$ is $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, this map from abstract polynomials to polynomial functions (in fact, it is an $R$-module homomorphism) is a bijection, but this is *not* true for general rings. In particular, for any finite ring $R$, which includes the case of finite fields $\Bbb F_{p^n}$, the (abstract polynomial)
$$q(X) := \prod_{r \in R} (X - r)$$
induces the zero function, as for any $r \in R$, the product $q(r)$ contains the factor $r - r = 0$. At least for fields $\Bbb F$, the ideal generated by $q(X)$ is the kernel of the about $\Bbb F$-module (in fact, $\Bbb F$-algebra) homomorphism, so we can identify the ring of polynomial functions with $\Bbb F[X] / \langle q(X) \rangle$.